# Keras asks for output shape that does not seem representative of the actual data

Tags: tensorflow, neural-network, keras, reshape

I am using this model to take an 84x84 image as input and 4 classes as output:

```python
def __buildModel(self):
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Conv2D(16, kernel_size=(8,8), strides=(4,4),
                     activation='relu',
                     input_shape=(None,84,84,)))
    model.add(Conv2D(32, kernel_size=(4,4), strides=(2,2), activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dense(256,activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dense(4,activation='linear'))

    model.compile(loss=keras.losses.categorical_crossentropy, optimizer=keras.optimizers.RMSprop())

    return model
```

I shape my input (state) and output (actions) to what I thought:

```python
actions = np.zeros((1,1,sampleSize,self.actionSize))
states = np.zeros((1,sampleSize,84,84))

self.model.fit(states,actions,epochs=1)
```

and I get the error:

```python
ValueError: Error when checking target: expected dense_2 to have shape (None, None, 9, 4) but got array with shape (1, 1, 126, 4)
```

So I changed it to:

```python
actions = np.zeros((1,sampleSize,9,self.actionSize))
```

but I get:

```python
InvalidArgumentError (see above for traceback): Incompatible shapes: [1,79,9,4] vs. [1,8,9,4]
 [[Node: loss/dense_2_loss/mul = Mul[T=DT_FLOAT, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"](_arg_dense_2_target_0_2, loss/dense_2_loss/Log)]]
```

Anyone know whats going on or if I made a mistake when making my model, I have been trying to fix this for days? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

See the `model.summary()`, you will see the shapes the model is using.

Notice that the order is `(images, side1, side2, channels)`.

You're inverting the `input_shape`, it should be `input_shape=(84,84,you_need_channels)`. The number of channels may be 1, if images are B&W, or 3 if they're RGB, 4 if they have an alpha channel, etc.

The sides will shrink along the convolutions, because they lose the borders. (You can prevent that with `padding='same'` in those layers).

Notice also that the `Dense` layers will keep the image sides.

You can collapse the sides with either `Flatten()` layers (may be good if you will always use sizze 84x84, or `GlobalMaxPooling2D()` or `GlobalAveragePooling2D()` if you intend to use variable size images.

Comment: I changed the input shape as you said to input_shape=(84,84,1) and the input to states = np.zeros((sampleSize,84,84,1)), now it asks for shape:
expected dense_2 to have shape (None, 9, 9, 4) but got array with shape (1, 79, 9, 4)

and the model summary is :
conv2d_1 (Conv2D)            (None, 20, 20, 16)        1040      
conv2d_2 (Conv2D)            (None, 9, 9, 32)          8224      
dense_1 (Dense)              (None, 9, 9, 256)         8448      
dense_2 (Dense)              (None, 9, 9, 4)           1028    

Do you have any idea why the 9 appears? thanks

Comment: I added a flatten layer between the convolution and the dense layers and it looks like it works now, it was dump of me to not do it, but im quite new to this so thank you! however I still don't know why the 9 was showig up

Comment: It's the resulting size of the convolution, you're using big filters with big strides, the result is a tiny image.